# Javascript AJAX call to Jquery Call

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to have my code written almost fully written in Jquery, I want to rewrite an AJAX call in Jquery.

It's a call from a webpage to a Tomcat servlet.

Similar code of my present situation:

```
var http = new XMLhttpRequest();
var url = "http://example.com/MessageController?action=send";

http.onreadystatechange = function ()
if (http.readyState == 4)
{
    if (http.status == 200){ var response = http.responseText;}
    else {/*code2*/}
};
http.async = false;
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send(string);
```

Which would be the best way to do this? `.ajax` or `.post`? Could you help me with some pseudo code to start this?

Comment: Do you want your call to be asynchronous?  Your current call will be blocking because you've set http.async = false, whereas jquery.ajax will be asynchronous by default.

Comment: Not sure. This is working fine. Asynchronous, would be not reloading the whole webpage?

Comment: Asynchronous means that your AJAX call won't block further javascript code and, usually more importantly, the browser's UI thread.  In other words, the browser won't "hang" while it's waiting to get the data back from the server.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wer/archive/2011/08/03/why-you-should-use-xmlhttprequest-asynchronously.aspx

Comment: oh yes, I need that the browser hangs, actually I made a `freezeDiv` to wait for the response. Great comment!

Comment: synchronous requests almost always cause a poor user experience.  In most cases, you can get better results by make an async request and manually preventing (through javascript) your user from actions which would cause issues if they occurred before the request completed.  It might be a little more work up front, but it may save you from some big headaches, even browser crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or (as you are using POST) [`.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://example.com/MessageController",
  type: "POST",
  data: { action: "send", yourStringName: "something" },
  async: false, // make sure you really need it
  contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}).done(function(response) { 
  console.log(response);
});
```

It doesn't matter which one you use, because `.post` is shorthand for `.ajax`.

Comment: Could you rewrite a bit more specific to my case? Like where do I write the Content type, where does the string that I want to pass goes...

Comment: Data which you want to post goes into data (I've put your action there) and if you want to modify default content type (which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`) then you can use `contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`, it can be found in the api docs.

Comment: I'll try to rewrite this again, in the question.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer, now it includes all requested options.

Comment: Made an edit to the Q. How to catch var `reponse` in your example?

Comment: Both answers suit me good, given both thumbs up, To try to be fair, How  to pick one?

Comment: I'll leave anwer to this question to you, after all it is you who should decide which is *better*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15013/discussion-between-jacktrades-and-des)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

```
var url="MessageController"
$.post(url, { action : "send"} ,function(data){
  //response from MessageController is in data variable
  //code 1
  alert(data)
}).error(function(){
      alert("error");  //code 2
   })
```

Assuming `MessageController` is some url in your domain and you are aware of the [same origin  policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Thanks. don't understand this -> in jquery doc, data is data to be sent to the server, nevertheless, you write that response is in data variable. Please write, where does the 'string' goes. Also how do I setup async 'false' here?

Comment: the data to the serer is the second parameter(action : "send"). The key name will be "action" and value is "send". you can give anythign here. The response from the server will be available in the variable data( you can give any name to this variable). Use firebug and see what data is goind and coming back

Comment: data will be equivalant as reponse

Comment: About Same origin policy check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849945/how-does-same-origin-policy-applies-to-browser-extensions)