# Chrome extension XSS possibility

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xss

This is a hypothetical question:

I want to build a Chrome extension that'll track a user's clicks on a subset of webpages where the extension is active, and send data as a POST or GET request via AJAX to an external server I have running somewhere. Is this possible at all, because it sounds like XSS to me? If it is XSS, are there any workarounds?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: To clarify, this question was posed to monitor the clicks *within the widget.*

Comment: This is hypothetically can be a law issue with real punishment

Comment: How/why? I'm basically injecting a small HTML form into the Bing homepage, and want to know what data the user submits on that form, what buttons they're clicking on, etc.

Comment: I'm sure this is privacy violation

Comment: This is completely possible; see [How does Same Origin Policy apply to browser extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849945/how-does-same-origin-policy-apply-to-browser-extensions/) (Short answer: it doesn't, really.)

Comment: @khalid13 Do you seriously not see the tremendous privacy violation such an extension introduces? It seems to fit the definition of [spyware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyware) quite nicely. Even if you operate *with user consent* (e.g., users are somehow okay with you collecting their entire search history), you'd still have a legal responsibility in many nations to protect the data you collect from outside eyes.

Comment: @khalid13 Carification: If you are injecting your own HTML widget and *only monitoring that injected widget*, and not Bing's search bar or anything else on the page, then you're probably okay (but still maybe not, depending what the widget does). Your question doesn't make it clear whether you are monitoring your own widget or all site activity.

Comment: @apsillers: I do see it, but this is a private extension to be released to a small set of users for a research experiment at a lab I'm working in. I'm not directly involved in the privacy/disclosure stuff, but I'm sure it'll be handled by the legal people. I am monitoring my own widget, so I think we should be good on that front. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a hypothetical answer *:

A chrome extension ... "can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions."

Source and instructions: [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)

* ... but you should take note of the comments concerning privacy and legality before implementing this!