# Why can Chrome execute javascript on other pages but I can't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Apologies if this is a roundabout way of asking this question, but I am a little confused about how the web and javascript work.

**What I want to do:** execute javascript on all pages of a list of urls I have found. (Specifically use jquery to pull info from them)

**Problem** I can't execute Javascript on these pages because they aren't mine and don't have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. So I can't load them (with AJAX) in order to use JQuery on them.

**BUT** Google Chrome can both load pages and execute javascript on them (with their developer's console). So if I wanted too, I could go to each page, open the developers console, and pull the information from there. If there's nothing stopping Chrome from accessing these, then why am I stopped? And, is there a way around this?

Thank you, and I hope my description makes sense. I've been researching this for a while but have found nothing that explains how seemingly inconsistent CORS is.

Comment: because... ajax is restricted by the same origin policy, but there is no such restriction for you visiting the page directly with the browser...

Comment: Browsers don't let site A load content on from site B by default, because the user might have logged into site B and have access to personal information that site A should not be able to steal. There is work underway to allow site A to anonymously load content from site B, to avoid the security concerns, but this has not been standardized.

Comment: @apsillers I think I've confused myself and that's not possible -- the `no-cors` option in [the Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) allows cross-domain requests from Service Workers, but the responses are still opaque unless passed to a page of the appropriate origin. Oops. The `crossorigin=anonymous` attribute creates internal anonymous cross-origin requests like I described, and I think the Fetch spec is being expanded to describe that behaviour, *but* AFAIK it's not going to be exposed through the public fetch API, so what I said is mistaken.

Comment: use tampermonkey to run your own scripts on any domain

Answer (score 2):

> I could go to each page, open the developers console, and pull the information from there. If there's nothing stopping Chrome from accessing these, then why am I stopped?

You're not stopped. You, the human at the keyboard, can do exactly as you say, by visiting each page as a top-level page.

What *is* stopped -- happily -- is *any and all scripts on the Web you happen to run* having the same level of visibility that you do. Based on your cookies and your network topology, you have a unique view into the Web. You can see your home router's control interface (on `192.168.1.1` or similar). You can see any local web server you're running on `127.0.0.1`. No one else can see these. If the same-origin policy were not in place, then any script that you loaded on the Web could inspect these.

> And, is there a way around this?

If you have some scripts that you trust absolutely (hopefully a significant subset of "all scripts that exist on the Web") that you *want* to be able to bypass the same-origin policy and see your full, cross-domain view of the Web, you could [load them as an extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions), which can act with elevated permissions beyond the abilities of normal web pages. (See [How does Same Origin Policy apply to browser extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11849945/710446))

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are looking to grab data from these pages that aren't yours and store it somewhere.  I have done this before with curl using php.  If you are looking to display these sites for users to interact in a different way, but starting from a page that is yours, you may be able to render these pages by grabbing the source html using curl and rendering it as a sort of proxy.

I've used this tutorial for something similar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kQN-3aNCeI .  Hopefully this gives you a start.  I think you should be a little more detailed in your question though to get more help.